# Angular2 with Karma: web-server 404

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, systemjs

I've managed to configure karma and **played a dummy test with success**. However, things get complicated as I try to implement a real test:

About my configuration: test files (spec) and `ts` files are in `app` folder. On the other hand, `js` files and `js.map` files are in `dist` folder.

Here is my karma conf file:

```
... 

   files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
      'karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: 'dist/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },    

      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: 'app/**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: 'app/**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: 'app/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'dist/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
  ],

  // Proxied base paths for loading assets
  proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": "base/app"
  },

  exclude: [],
  preprocessors: {},
```

It gives me the following error:

```
START:
...
05 11 2016 21:42:53.211:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/dist/js/app/account/account.component
05 11 2016 21:42:53.217:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/dist/js/app/account/account.service
Chrome 54.0.2840 (Mac OS X 10.12.1) ERROR
  {
    "originalErr": {}
  }

Finished in 0.827 secs / 0 secs

SUMMARY:
✔ 0 tests completed
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I'm using `systemjs`. After some research, it looks like something is wrong with my conf (and with the way I'm providing files to karma). I've tried to match angular2-starter repositories but I can't find a project configuration similar to mine.

Other configuration files are available on Github (branch feature/tests):

- [karma-test-shim.js](https://github.com/DavidLevayer/countable/blob/feature/tests/karma-test-shim.js)
- [full karma-conf.js](https://github.com/DavidLevayer/countable/blob/feature/tests/karma.conf.js)
- [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/DavidLevayer/countable/blob/feature/tests/tsconfig.json)
- [Test file (spec)](https://github.com/DavidLevayer/countable/blob/feature/tests/app/account/account.component.spec.ts)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out!?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/DavidLevayer/countable/